# How do you nearly darken an image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I have been trying to darken pictures of animals, but it only darkens the darks and I wanted the whites to darken.

What are ways to accomplish the style?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you're looking for, just simply add a Brightness/Contrast filter with both brightness and contrast set to 0. Then change the blend mode of the filter to "Multiply". This will darken the image, hopefully in the way you want.

[image: Darkened Image]

However, this is not the only way to darken the image. The same result can be achieved by applying other filters such as Levels (Ctrl + L) and Curves. Play around with the values until you get what you want.

Comment: Yes, Levels will darken it all together.

Answer (score 1):

These images aren't "darkened". These are **illustrations** and were drawn/painted to have that appearance.

If you want the same general style, you need to draw/paint in the same general manner. Not everything is merely a "photoshop trick" to accomplish. Some things actually take artistic skill.

Comment: Down vote all you want... Software can't replace artistic talent.

Answer (score 0):

I would play with the [Shadows/Highlights](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjust-shadow-highlight-detail.html) dialog box under 'Image → Adjustments', which will basicly darken the whites, brighten the blacks and also tone down the contrast and can easily produce this look by dragging a few sliders around.